# Why are those implication true? (Hoare logic)

Tags: logic

I try do understand the Hoare logic especial the Rule of Consequence.

Now I have two implication where I do not unterstand the implikation

1: $\left\{y=\frac{n !}{x !} \wedge x \geq 0 \wedge x \geq 1\right\} \Rightarrow x \geq 0$

2: $$
\begin{aligned}
\{y&\left.=\frac{n !}{x !} \wedge x \geq 0 \wedge x<1\right\} \\
& \Rightarrow\left\{y=\frac{n !}{x !} \wedge x=0\right\}
\end{aligned}
$$

I tried do solve it logically, but after 4 hours I quit and have to ask this question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The logic symbol $\wedge$ stands for "and". In this case the meaning is that all three of those statements are true so the middle one must be true.
2. I assume in this case $x$ is an integer. Using the above reasoning the implication is clear for the first statement. Next, $x = 0$ because it is a nonnegative integer strictly less than $1$.